# Edit vs own answer

Tags: discussion, answers, editing

There were 2 answers for [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/35445/do-properties-of-magic-weapons-stack-when-using-two-weapon-fighting), both more than 50% right.
I ended up adding my answer, but should I change the other answers?

On one hand they contain factual errors, so they *should* be corrected.
On the other hand we will end up with 3 identical answers, what is the point of that?

So what is the preferred action in these cases?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The guideline for editing is stated as this [in our editing help](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/editing):

> ### When should I edit posts?
>
> Any time you see a post that needs improvement and are inclined to suggest an edit, you are welcome to do so. The original author of a question or answer may always edit their own post, regardless of reputation level.
>
> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
> - To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
> - To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
> - To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
> - To add related resources or hyperlinks

One of the most solid guidelines is that second point: **your editing should not be changing the meaning of a post.** However, you can clarify their meaning, which extends to ironing over a small trip-up in the rules or poor usage of terminology.

So, generally minor factual corrections are OK, but if you find yourself rewriting a substantial portion of the post just to correct it, you should probably just be downvoting it. How much is a substantial portion is your responsibility to make a judgement call on.

In your case, I'm guessing that in correcting those posts, you would be changing their meaning. Use your downvote instead.