# Should I remove the second part of this answer?

Tags: discussion

Reading [this question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3563/1271), I noticed that it (likely unintentionally) also may apply to [an answer I wrote](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/37490/1271): I wonder if I'd better remove the second part of it, then.

The first part just concisely answers the question, while the second one is a longer, relevant anectode. While I think this anectode could be interesting and useful, I'm no longer sure it's the case, and I also fear it could be considered a rant (it isn't intended to be, but that's beside the point).

Would this answer be better removing the second part? Could this second part be good as *a question*, such as "Is my analysis of this situation correct?".

Answer (score 5):

I don't think so, you're enhancing the point with a reasonably relevant anecdote. As far as I can tell the meta question in question was targeted at answers that contained tangents that are related to the concept but completely unrelated to the frame of the question.