# Was my edit to this answer on a Q&A about Spell Sniper an edit too far?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, answers, editing

I recently made [a substantial edit](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/139157/3) to [this answer to the Q&A "Which spells benefit from the Spell Sniper feat?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/139157/2788), that would make a good dupe target.

The [help page on editing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/editing) says:

> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it.

I feel the edit I made is in line with those, along with covering a mistake in the original post (i.e. there are exceptions).

However previous Q&As on meta ([Editing someone else's answer vs. commenting](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6230/editing-someone-elses-answer-vs-commenting), and [When editing, how drastic is too drastic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5726/when-editing-how-drastic-is-too-drastic)) have been inconclusive, and disagree on whether to add a comment or make an edit. The [sole answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6230/editing-someone-elses-answer-vs-commenting/6231#6231) to the first Q&A says, in part:

> #### Comment
>
> When you think the answer is mostly good but you wish it would address an additional point

While [mxyzplk's answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5726/when-editing-how-drastic-is-too-drastic/5729#5729) to the second Q&A says:

> [...] edits shouldn't change the nature of the answer - if you're changing a yes to a no, that's bad [...] We edit to add info, to add clarification from comments so comments can be deleted, to copyedit... Whatever seems like it's improving the answer, while maintaining the point of the answer.

Did my edit to cover edge cases go too far, based on the above?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Your edit did go too far

Because the answer, from your point of view<sup>1</sup>, is (partially) wrong, and you tried making it right. That is best done by **submitting a new answer**, one that is right, and backing it up accordingly. If you think the answer is mostly right but there is one point you disagree with (i.e., you think it is a mistake), it's best left as a comment. If the original poster doesn't change it (either because they left the site or because they disagree), you can, again, submit a new answer, if you consider that the mistake is harmful enough that shouldn't go unaddressed.

Editing is for clarifying things *that are already in the answer*. Your edit was something completely new to the answer, i.e.,

> When you think the answer is mostly good but you wish it would address an additional point

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm not even sure it is, in fact, wrong. Spell Sniper doesn't require the attack roll to be part of casting the spell. On the other hand, there is the distinction between *requiring* you to make the attack and *allowing* you to make it.

Comment: Agreed.  I would have rejected it in a review queue, or reverted it if the edit were to one of my answers.

Comment: Put a different way, the original author of the answer has a right to be wrong (I'm talking in a general sense here, not questioning the correctness of that specific answer). Edits aren't meant to correct their argument or conclusion, just to correct their spelling or wrong page number or formatting, etc. Submitting a new answer is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Accepted, and I've posted a new answer to the question.